# Trouble evaluating the following integral

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I am having trouble performing the following integration which comes from a larger function (let me know if I inputted the code wrong from Mathematica so I can fix it!) and even with assumptions, Mathematica just gives back the original line of code. Any suggestions on how to help Mathematica evaluate this I would be grateful, thanks! (I can also post in Latex what the integral looks like if that may help anyone).

(Note: I do need/want the symbolic version of this and not a numerical form, so I haven't tried NIntegrate[] yet. I am particularly interested in the behavior of the Q's and m's (specifically ln(-Q^2/m^2) and how that behaves. This is the final step in a computation from QFT if anyone was wondering).

```
Integrate[SeriesData[\[Epsilon], 0, {Complex[0, 
Rational[1, 4]] Pi^(-2) (
2 m^4 - 4 m^2 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) - (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (
 6 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) + Q^2 (5 - 12 x + 8 x^2)))
 Subscript[m, 1]^2 Subscript[m, 2]^2, Complex[0, 
Rational[1, 16]]
 Pi^(-2) ((-8)
   m^4 + m^2 ((-8) Q^2 (-1 + x) x + 20 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)) + (
  m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (
  14 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) + Q^2 (
    15 - 36 x + 20 x^2)) + Rational[-1, 4] (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (
  16 m^2 + 4 Q^2 (5 - 12 x + 8 x^2)) (
  1 - 2 EulerGamma + Log[
   16] + 2 Log[Pi] + 2 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) - 4 (
  m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 (
 2 - 3 EulerGamma + Log[
  64] + 3 Log[Pi] + 3 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) - 4 m^4 (
 EulerGamma - Log[4 Pi/(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)]))
 Subscript[m, 1]^2 Subscript[m, 2]^2, Complex[0, 
Rational[1, 384]]
 Pi^(-2) ((-220) (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 + 48 (
   m^2 + Q^2 (-1 + x) x)^2 - 6 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (
 28 m^2 + Q^2 (17 - 60 x + 44 x^2)) - 6 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (
 20 m^2 + Q^2 (15 - 36 x + 20 x^2)) (-1 + 2 EulerGamma - Log[
 16] - 2 Log[
  Pi] - 2 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) + 56 (
   m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 (
  2 - 3 EulerGamma + Log[
   64] + 3 Log[
    Pi] + 3 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) + Rational[1, 2] (
  m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) ((-16) m^2 - 4 Q^2 (5 - 12 x + 8 x^2)) (
  6 + 6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + 24 Log[2]^2 + Log[
   4096] + 6 Log[Pi] + 24 Log[2] Log[
    Pi] + 6 Log[Pi]^2 - 6 EulerGamma (
   1 + Log[16] + 2 Log[Pi]) + 6 (
    1 - 2 EulerGamma + Log[16] + 2 Log[Pi])
     Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)] + 6 Log[(
       m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]^2) - 12 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 (
 8 + 6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + 16 Log[2] + 24 Log[2]^2 + 8 Log[
   Pi] + 24 Log[2] Log[Pi] + 6 Log[Pi]^2 - 4 EulerGamma (
  2 + Log[64] + 3 Log[Pi]) + 4 (
   2 - 3 EulerGamma + Log[64] + 3 Log[Pi])
    Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)] + 6 Log[(
      m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]^2) + 4 m^4 (
  6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + 24 Log[2]^2 + 24 Log[2] Log[
    Pi] + 6 Log[Pi]^2 - 12 EulerGamma Log[4 Pi] - 12 (
   EulerGamma - Log[4 Pi])
    Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x)
       x)^(-1)] + 6 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]^2) + 96 m^2 (
  m^2 + Q^2 (-1 + x) x) (EulerGamma - Log[
  4 Pi/(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)]))
 Subscript[m, 1]^2 Subscript[m, 2]^2}, -1, 2, 1], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  m > 0 \[And] Q > 0 \[And] \[Epsilon] > 0 \[And] 
  m \[Element] Reals \[And] Q \[Element] Reals]
```

Comment: I've not looked at this in detail, but the behaviour might depend strongly on whether `m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x` is ever zero in the integration interval.  Supplying conditions that ensure that it is not might help.

Comment: @mikado how would I write that assumption into the integral? I am not sure about that though since I do want it to be able to go to the massless limit ($m=0$) but the ratio $m^2/Q^2 = x(1-x)\geq 0$ is true. So how would I insert that?

Comment: Since `0<x<1 => 0<(1-x)x<1/4`, I think that `m>Q/2>0` could be a suitable condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

It is more efficient to convert the [`SeriesData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) to a normal expression. For example,

```
series = Series[E^x, {x, 0, 4}];

Integrate[series, {x, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.0680269, 103/60} *)

Integrate[series // Normal, {x, 0, 1}] // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.0000175881, 103/60} *)
```

Your integrand as a normal expression is

```
integrand = 
  SeriesData[ϵ, 
    0, {Complex[0, 
       Rational[1, 4]] Pi^(-2) (2 m^4 - 
        4 m^2 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) - (m^2 - 
           Q^2 (1 - x) x) (6 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) + 
           Q^2 (5 - 12 x + 8 x^2))) Subscript[m, 1]^2 Subscript[m, 2]^2, 
     Complex[0, 
       Rational[1, 16]] Pi^(-2) ((-8) m^4 + 
        m^2 ((-8) Q^2 (-1 + x) x + 20 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)) + (m^2 - 
           Q^2 (1 - x) x) (14 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) + 
           Q^2 (15 - 36 x + 20 x^2)) + 
        Rational[-1, 
          4] (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (16 m^2 + 4 Q^2 (5 - 12 x + 8 x^2)) (1 - 
           2 EulerGamma + Log[16] + 2 Log[Pi] + 
           2 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) - 
        4 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 (2 - 3 EulerGamma + Log[64] + 3 Log[Pi] + 
           3 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) - 
        4 m^4 (EulerGamma - Log[4 Pi/(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)])) Subscript[m, 
        1]^2 Subscript[m, 2]^2, 
     Complex[0, 
       Rational[1, 384]] Pi^(-2) ((-220) (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 + 
        48 (m^2 + Q^2 (-1 + x) x)^2 - 
        6 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (28 m^2 + Q^2 (17 - 60 x + 44 x^2)) - 
        6 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) (20 m^2 + Q^2 (15 - 36 x + 20 x^2)) (-1 + 
           2 EulerGamma - Log[16] - 2 Log[Pi] - 
           2 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) + 
        56 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 (2 - 3 EulerGamma + Log[64] + 3 Log[Pi] + 
           3 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]) + 
        Rational[1, 
          2] (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x) ((-16) m^2 - 
           4 Q^2 (5 - 12 x + 8 x^2)) (6 + 6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + 
           24 Log[2]^2 + Log[4096] + 6 Log[Pi] + 24 Log[2] Log[Pi] + 
           6 Log[Pi]^2 - 6 EulerGamma (1 + Log[16] + 2 Log[Pi]) + 
           6 (1 - 2 EulerGamma + Log[16] + 
              2 Log[Pi]) Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)] + 
           6 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]^2) - 
        12 (m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^2 (8 + 6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + 16 Log[2] + 
           24 Log[2]^2 + 8 Log[Pi] + 24 Log[2] Log[Pi] + 6 Log[Pi]^2 - 
           4 EulerGamma (2 + Log[64] + 3 Log[Pi]) + 
           4 (2 - 3 EulerGamma + Log[64] + 
              3 Log[Pi]) Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)] + 
           6 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]^2) + 
        4 m^4 (6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + 24 Log[2]^2 + 24 Log[2] Log[Pi] + 
           6 Log[Pi]^2 - 12 EulerGamma Log[4 Pi] - 
           12 (EulerGamma - Log[4 Pi]) Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)] + 
           6 Log[(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)^(-1)]^2) + 
        96 m^2 (m^2 + Q^2 (-1 + x) x) (EulerGamma - 
           Log[4 Pi/(m^2 - Q^2 (1 - x) x)])) Subscript[m, 1]^2 Subscript[m, 
        2]^2}, -1, 2, 1] // Normal;
```

Simplify the integrand prior to integrating

```
LeafCount /@ {integrand, integrand2 = integrand // Simplify}

(* {954, 787} *)
```

Expand the integrand into a sum and integrate term-by-term

```
integrand2 // Expand // Head

(* Plus *)
```

The integration is quite slow: (* leave out the Short to see the full result *)

```
(int = Assuming[
     m > 0 ∧ Q > 0 ∧ ϵ > 0 ∧ 
      m ∈ Reals ∧ Q ∈ Reals,
     Simplify[Integrate[#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ (integrand2 // Expand)]]) // 
  Short[#, 20] & // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Including the given conditions in the assumptions improves the timing; however, the integration is still quite slow,

```
(int2 = Assuming[
     m > 0 ∧ Q > 0 ∧ ϵ > 0 ∧ 
      m ∈ Reals ∧ Q ∈ Reals && 
      2*m > Q && (Q <= Re[Sqrt[-4*m^2 + Q^2]] || 
        NotElement[Sqrt[-4*m^2 + Q^2], Reals]),
     Simplify[Integrate[#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ 
  (integrand2 // Expand)]]) // 
  Short[#, 20] & // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

However, the quicker result increases the LeafCount:

```
LeafCount /@ {int, int2}

(* {8282, 9495} *)
```

Comment: Is there a way to expand the $\log(m^2-Q^2x(1-x))$ within Mathematica such that I get the following output, $\log(1-(Q/m)^2x(1-x)) + log(m^2)$ or for those of with the inverse inside the log, write it as $\log(1/(m^2 - Q^2x(1-x)) = -\log(m^2 - Q^2x(1-x))$? Or would this not even help the situation?

Comment: Also, when I put this on my bigger computer, it does the entire integral in about 1 minute. The condition Mathematica puts on the integral is that $2m>Q$ and $Q\leq Re[\sqrt{-4m^2+Q^2}]$.

Comment: Since `Assuming[m > 0 && Q > 0, Log[m^2 - Q^2 x (1 - x)] == Log[m^2*(1 - (Q/m)^2 x (1 - x))] // Simplify]` evaluates to `True`; just define `rule = Log[m^2*(1 - (Q/m)^2 x (1 - x))] :> Log[1 - (Q/m)^2 x (1 - x)] + Log[m^2];` and use `expr /. rule` as required.